# How do I show an error message when I have an invalid log in?

Tags: python, html, authentication

I'm working on a web app right now and I don't know how to display an error message when the user types in an invalid log in name. How do I go about this?

this is my login.html

```
{% block body %}
  <h1>Login</h1>
  {% if error %}
    <p>Invalid Username</p>
  {% endif %}
  
  <form method="POST" action="{{ url_for('login') }}">
    <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Your Username">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

<a href='{{variable6}}'>Sign Up</a>
{% endblock %}
```

this is my app.py

```
@app.route("/login", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def login():
    if flask.request.method == "GET":
        return flask.render_template("login.html")
    if flask.request.method == "POST":
        username = flask.request.form["username"]
        cursor.execute(
            "SELECT user_name FROM public.users WHERE user_name = %s", [username]
        )
        results = cursor.fetchall()
        if len(results) != 0: # if a user exists, "log" them in
            return flask.redirect(flask.url_for("main"))
        else:
            return flask.render_template("login.html")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that your problem is that you are not defining what the "error" variable is, you could fix this by when you are returning the render_template in the last line of app.py, adding error=True, leaving you with this as your last line for app.py.

```
return flask.render_template("login.html", error=True)
```

As otherwise Jinja (the templating language you used in login.html) would not know what error and would get the type None as the value of error in the {% if error %} statement in login.html and since None is not equal to true, it would skip over the code you want to run.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: @MattNguyen Sorry to bother you, but if that was the correct answer could you please mark it as being the right answer so this question could be quickly recognised as resolved and also so that in the future if people have a problem like this they will know it helped. Thank you and I apologize for bothering you with this request.